# hide a div from top to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering if there is a way to hide a `div` from the top to the bottom. Below is the code:

```
$("#viewport").hide("blind", {direction: "vertical"},
                        4000, function (){
                            //do something
                            $("#viewport").fadeIn(3000);
                        });
```

It works fine, except for the way of hidden which is from bottom to the top.
Some suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `direction: "vertical"` with `direction: "down"`:

```
$("#viewport").hide("blind", {direction: "down"},
                    4000, function (){
                        //do something
                        $("#viewport").fadeIn(3000);
                    });
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/qtfdm